# Why to use blowfish for passwords?

Tags: hash, passwords, blowfish

I'm a little confused about password-safe-keeping.
Let's say I've got database with user-account table. 
And this is the place where i keep passwords.
At this time i'm using salted sha1.

I read Blowfish based function are better then sha1 because they need more time to process request.

Is there any reason why not to use salted sha1 and just limit login attempt count to some reasonable number (for example 50times per hour) as a 'firewall' to bruteforce attacks?

person who is working with this database has no need to bruteforce anything because
he can change records by queries.

Comment: @paddy Simple SHA-2 is bit designed for password hashing, it's fast. If you want to use SHA-2 you need to use PBKDF-SHA-2 or the SHA-2 based crypt algorithms. BCrypt(which the OP misnamed Blowfish) is designed for password hashing and slow. Even when using an equivalent work-factor bcrypt is better than SHA-2 based algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

With blowfish based function, you surely mean the **BCrypt** hash function. As you already stated BCrypt is designed to be slow (need some computing time), that's the only advantage over other fast hash functions, but this is crucial.

With an off-the-shelf GPU, you are able to calculate about [3 Giga](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-lite/#performance) hash values per second, so you can brute-force a whole english dictionary with 5'000'000 words in less than **2 milliseconds**. Even if SHA-1 is a safe hash function, that makes it inappropriate for hashing passwords.

BCrypt has a **cost factor**, which can be adapted to future, and therefore faster, hardware. The cost factor determines how many iterations of hashing are performed. Recently i wrote a [tutorial about hashing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/hash.html), i would invite you to have a look at it.

Your point about restricting login attempts makes sense, but the hashing should protect the passwords in case the attacker has access to the database (SQL-injection). Of course you can limit the login attempts, but that has nothing to do with hashing, you could even store the passwords plaintext in this scenario.

Comment: That's exacly the answer i was looking for ;)  Because i was confused why server-side hash algoritm is better when its slower... didn't think about accessing database in some other way (like sqli). I always run all form input via regexp but you never know... ;p  Now i've got another question.  (i've not dive into your article yet) If bcrypt is a hash algorithm... is the output of bcrypt function is always the length? (like sha1 or md5).  And i need to look for bcrypt for php.  (php got only 'crypt' and 'hash' functions.. but im not sure how they works. And what about collisions in bcrypt

Comment: @Tomek - The output of BCrypt is always a string with a length of 60 characters (including the salt and the cost factor). Have a look at the provided link, you will find the tutorial as well as informations about a PHP-implementation (`crypt` is explained, PHPass is recommended), and you can play around with SQL-injection. By the way, you should always escape user input, before adding them to SQL (with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`), regex is only good for validating user input.

Comment: But what if characters that are 'needed to be escaped' are not allowed at all?  I read your article. And whats the question for me now is why the salt is stored unsecured.  For example; if someone crack into database and got hash and salt he is able to bruteforce by using dictionary and appending/prependig the salt to the every word from dictionary

Comment: @Tomek - In this case, let's say you have validated an email address, you don't need to escape the user input, but it does no harm if you do. Normally escaping all string values is good, better to escape an unnecessary case, than to forget one.

Comment: You are right. I looked into code in PHP part of your page and i found a bug in the 'dictionary' object for arrays. You are using isset() to check if an array_key_exists.  This is wrong, as $a['null'] = NULL;   isset($a['null']) will return FALSE when array_key_exists('null',$a) will return the TRUE (because array key indeed exists)

Comment: @Tomek - I see that you read the page carefully, thanks for your comment! In this case it's a feature :-) if you look at the comment of `setValue()` it states _A value of null will delete the key_. According to many articles in the internet, the function `array_key_exists()` can be very slow.

Comment: yes. but this is the difference between unset(array[key]) and array[key] = null.  for arrays the behavior of garbagecollector seems to be different...  Back to the cryptography:   Do i get the salt and pepper concept right?   When i use blowfish the function takes 22 char long salt...  this 'salt' that im giving to the function is just salt or salt + pepper? ;)  so do i have to mix (for example 15 char long salt with 7char long pepper) before i use bcrypt?

Comment: @Tomek - Noo, the salt is just the salt and will be added usually by the BCrypt function itself (it creates a 22 character random string). The salt is visible in the resulting hash-value and will be stored in the database. A pepper should never go into the database, you can append it to the password before hashing, so it gets mixed up.

Comment: @Tomek - Just completed the [Bcrypt implementation](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt) with an optional pepper, to show it's usage.

Comment: Btw. I noticed you are using function in your bcrypt. I've putted this into class. Btw.   Using 'die' to output the error message is an old_school method from non Object_oriented php.  Try to use exceptions.    Something like this.  If(!$something) throw new exception.   ;) that helps in bigger projects.

Comment: @Tomek - Thanks for your suggestions. It's a good thing to create a class from the functions, they actually _where_ a class first. Then i decided to make loose functions, because i want to present my examples as basic and easy to understand as possible. Making a class out of it is easy, but presenting a class will raise the bar for some developers. I intend to take your advice with the `unset()` though.

Comment: As a side-note: An upcoming version of php will include an easy to use password hashing API based on bcrypt.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Yes that was very [good news](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/16506/8343), it will be part of PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Storing passwords in Blowfish is more secure than SHA-1 because, as of now, there has been no reported method of obtaining the value of a Blowfish-encrypted string. SHA-1, on the other hand, does have reported methods of obtaining data from encrypted strings. **You cannot trust SHA-1 to prevent someone from obtaining its data.**

If you are open to suggestion, I don't see a need to work with two-way encryption at all as you are storing passwords. Hashing your users passwords with a salted **SHA-256** method may be an option. Allowing your users to reset their own passwords via Email is generally considered a good policy, and it results in a data set that cannot be easily cracked.

If you *do* require two-way encryption for any reason, aside from Blowfish, **AES-256** (Rijndael) or **Twofish** are also currently secure enough to handle sensitive data. Don't forget that you are free to use multiple algorithms to store encrypted data.

On the note of brute forcing, it has little to do with encrypted database storage. You are looking at a full security model when you refer to methods of attack. Using a deprecated algorithm and "making up for it" by implementing policies to prevent ease of attack is **not** considered a mature approach to security.

**In Short**

- Use one way hashing for storing passwords, allow users to reset via email
- Don't be afraid use multiple methods to store encrypted data
- If you must use an encryption/decryption scheme, keep your keys safe and only use proven algorithms
- Preventing brute force attacks is a good mindset, but it will only slow someone down or encourage them to search for other points of entry

Don't take this as gospel: when it comes to security everyone has different requirements, the more research you do the better your methods will become. If you don't completely encapsulate your sensitive data with a full-on security policy, you may get a nasty surprise down the track.

Source: Wikipedia, http://eprint.iacr.org/2005/010

Comment: I suppose that the OP meant BCrypt with "Blowfish based function", not the function for encryption itself. Like SHA-1, the SHA-256 function is ways too fast for hashing passwords, and allows to brute-force easily.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any reason why not to use salted sha1 and just limit login
>   attempt count to some reasonable number (for example 50times per hour)
>   as a 'firewall' to bruteforce attacks?

If you don't encrypt your passwords with any decent algorithm you are failing basic security precautions.

**Why isn't 'just' blocking login attempts safe?**

Well *beside* the fact you would need to block EVERY possible entrance, eg:

- ssh
- webservices (your webapp, phpmyadmin, openpanel, etcetera)
- ftp
- *lots more*

You would also need to trust every user that has access to the database and server, I wouldn't like people to read my password, but what I dislike even more, is you deciding for me, metaforically speaking :-)

Maybe someone else can shed light on the Blowfish vs SHA discussion, although I doubt that part is a stackworthy formatted question